Can you have a ground plane and a VCC plane right next to each other when designing a PCB?
I have never designed a PCB before.  This is my first time.
In the picture below I have all my VCC pins highlighted in white that need to be connected together along with a VCC plane that encloses all 3 of the highlighted pins and connects them together. The VCC plane is the bluish square with the green dots. I also have an entire ground plane that covers all my board which is the red square line on the top of the picture.

Is it okay to have a VCC plane and a ground plane right next to each other? Will this ever create a short circuit? I am also unsure if my VCC plane surrounding the 3 pins are actually connecting all 3 of the highlighted pins together or not.

Just to be clear, if these are on the same layer, you should refer to them as pours, polygons, regions, fills, etc. but not planes. A plane would generally refer to the entire layer.

Yes, you can have two fills or copper pours of different voltages next to each other. The gap between them, known as the clearance, depends on the voltage difference and the PCB manufacturer capabilities. The gap must meet or exceed the manufacturer capability first and foremost.
To calculate clearance for voltage differences, you can refer to IPC-2221 or IEC 60950-1/61010-1 (referred to in this question). You didn't specify what voltage you were working with.
If you are working with "low" voltages (< 48 V) you can use 0.1 mm as a good minimum, but this may be smaller than your manufacturer can reliably produce. For example the popular OSH Park service requires a minimum clearance of 0.1524 mm on their inexpensive 2-layer boards. (If you aren't using solder mask, increase the clearance to 0.6 mm.)
The three pads you are concerned about are connected, but the thermal relief may be confusing you. That is what causes the removal of copper from quadrants around the pad to form a "+" shape and is done to maintain an electrical connection but restrict heat flow to aid in soldering.

Fantastic answer! Thanks for going into detail

Nothing wrong with that, in and of itself.  Ensure adequate clearance for the applied voltage and environmental conditions, and avoid running signals directly under it for reasons of EMC or signal quality.
